# Passing get parameter from javascript to php destroys formatting

Tags: php, javascript

I format text with javascript asigning `+` to every emtpy space like this

```
var ft = text.replace(/ /g,"+");
```

Then I pass `ft` to a php script via jquery ajax as an get argument.

But

```
print $_GET['text'];
```

gives me the text with empty spaces instead +.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using some debugger for checking your sending data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get familiar with the concept of [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

PHP's `urldecode` function will run against all `$_GET` variables by default, so if you want to see raw input, use [`rawurldecode`](https://www.php.net/rawurldecode):

```
$encoded = array_map('rawurldecode', $_GET);

echo $encoded['text']; //blah+blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it's a good idea to use [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to pass data from javascript to PHP.